# Stacking Google Sheets Queries

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to run multiple Google Sheets Queries on one page verically, so it can be downloaded as a PDF report. The issue is the length of the data in the returned tables varies, so I am not sure where on the sheet to place the second query. e.g. if i place the Query in A1 and the second in A10, but the first returns 15 rows of data, I want the second table to come after it. Any suggestions? Obviously, I know I could add a LIMIT but really need to return all rows of data.

I tried placing them in the correct loactions but get an error:
Array was not expanded as it will overwite data in XX

Answer (score 0):

You can stack your different queries in one single cell.

```
=VSTACK(query1,query2,query3....)
```

Replace query1,2,3 with your different formulas . Also, if they may have different amount of columns or some query may return empty, you can use wrap it in IFNA